# Find an entire function with the following properties

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help with the following question, I am not sure where to start.

Find an entire function $f$ with the following properties:

1) $f$ has a zero at the origin

2) All the zeros of $f$ lie on the line $y=x$ on the complex plane, with adjacent zeros separated by a distance of 1.

3) There holds $f = \big(\frac{1}{2}\exp\frac{i\pi}{4}\big)$ = 2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(z)$ has all zeros on the real axis, separated by $\pi$.
In general a function $a\sin(bz)$ will have its zeros on a line with constant separation.

Comment: You might want to call this a hint.